# StackLayout: Children property cannot be assigned to

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this simple piece of code in Xamarin.Forms:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ReflectedColors
{
    public class ColorBlocksPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ColorBlocksPage()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {

            };
        }
    }
}
```

I click on `c` inside the `StackLayout` member initializer so as to set the `Children` collection and I get:

[image]

As you can `Children` is not there.

If I try to write

```
Content = new StackLayout
{
    Children = new Label { Text = "Test"}
};
```

I get the following error when trying to build my solution:

> Error CS0200  Property or indexer 'Layout.Children' cannot be
>   assigned to -- it is read only

I must be doing something stupid but unfortunately have no clue on what could be the source of this problem.

Comment: Check the example at https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the Children property to the new label.
Correct way to set the children property:

```
Content = new StackLayout
{
    Children = {new Label { Text = "Test"}}
};
```

Comment: I knew it was something stupid! I still don't understand why the IntelliSense doesn't show the property though.